# Trouble joining tables with LIKE condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

Need help on a sql script looking between 2 tables but the join columns don't exactly batch.

**Table1**

> ```
> FileName   Location
>
> abc        C:\file
>
> abc_TR     C:\fileTR
>
> xyz        C:\file
> ```

**Table2**

> ```
> FileName                TimeSentIn
>
> abc_20230101            2023-01-01 15:35
>
> abc_TR_20230101         2023-01-01 10:35
>
> xyz_20230103            2023-01-01 15:30
>
> rogert                  2023-01-01 15:31
>
> footing_20230105-0545   2023-01-01 14:20
> ```

I need the output to be:

> ```
> Table1.FileName    Table2.TimeSentIn
>
> abc                2023-01-01 15:35
>
> abc_TR             2023-01-01 10:35
>
> xyz                2023-01-01 15:30
> ```

Is there any sql script I can use for this? I tried to use a LIKE condition in a join but that gave me duplicates for abc and abc_TR

Thanks,

Dan

Comment: What version of SQL are you using?  E.g. MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle, etc.

Comment: sql server, microsoft sql

Comment: What does the iso date part of the Filename string represent? Why is for example `xyz_20230103` not the same date as the `TimeSentIn`? Should it be the same? If it was you could remove it before matching. Do you always have a right-most section preceded by underscore that needs to be removed?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS file_location
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS file_sent


CREATE TABLE file_location (
  FileName VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  Location VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO file_location (FileName, Location)
VALUES ('abc', 'C:\\file'), ('abc_TR', 'C:\\fileTR'), ('xyz', 'C:\\file');

CREATE TABLE file_sent (
  FileName VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  TimeSentIn DATETIME NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO file_sent (FileName, TimeSentIn)
VALUES ('abc_20230101', '2023-01-01 15:35:00'), ('abc_TR_20230101', '2023-01-01 10:35:00'), ('xyz_20230103', '2023-01-01 15:30:00'), ('rogert', '2023-01-01 15:31:00'), ('footing_20230105-0545', '2023-01-01 14:20:00');


SELECT file_location.FileName
     , file_location.Location
     , file_sent.TimeSentIn
FROM file_location
JOIN file_sent 
  ON file_location.FileName = REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(file_sent.FileName), 10, LEN(file_sent.FileName)));
```